# Razor function to get image path from action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a method to display the photo of logged user in a layout page.

It looks like the method is fine, and returns for me the image path, but I don't know to make it works on `<img src="">`, or I can do it with some razor function?

If I call my method from url like `http://localhost:29469/User/LoadPhoto`, it returns the correct path.

The layout is not typed, so I can not display it like `Model.Attribute`

```
public ActionResult LoadPhoto()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<User>(new ERPIdentityDbContext());
        var userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore);         

        var xUser = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        string xPhotoPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/Users/") + xUser.FotoPath ;
        return Content(xPhotoPath);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I want to use return for `LoadPhoto` method in `<img src="">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your photos are JPGs, return a `File ActionResult` with the `image/jpeg` content type:

```
string xPhotoPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/Users/") + xUser.FotoPath ;
return File(xPhotoPath,"image/jpeg");
```

Comment: @LeandroLemos no problem, you can mark this as the answer if you'd like.